# when there is a bigger screen make views grow

Tags: android, android-layout

this is my layout code
i use like root a grid layout and then for every row a frame layout inside that frame layout two frame layouts with image and txt...

```
<GridLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:columnCount="1"
android:rowCount="2">

<FrameLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <FrameLayout
        android:layout_width="200dp"
        android:layout_height="220dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="2dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="2dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="0.1dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="2dp"
        android:layout_row="1"
        android:layout_column="1">

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="150dp"
            android:layout_height="190dp"
            android:id="@+id/am"
            android:layout_gravity="top|center_horizontal"
            android:src="@drawable/black" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="153dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
            android:text="text"
            android:id="@+id/w"
            android:layout_gravity="bottom|center"

            android:layout_marginBottom="10dp" />

    </FrameLayout>

    <FrameLayout
        android:layout_width="200dp"
        android:layout_height="220dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="2dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="2dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="0dp"
        android:layout_row="1"
        android:layout_column="0"
        android:layout_gravity="right|center_vertical">

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="150dp"
            android:layout_height="190dp"
            android:id="@+id/imageView"
            android:layout_gravity="top|center"
            android:src="@drawable/black" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
            android:text="text"
            android:id="@+id/textView2"
            android:layout_gravity="bottom|center"
            android:layout_marginBottom="10dp" />
    </FrameLayout>

</FrameLayout>
```

this is how its seen

[image]

looks cool rigth? 
well this is my problem when i take this to a bigger screen this happends

[image]

well i dont whant this i whant that the text and images grow to take half of screen like first one...

HOW I DO THIS!!!

Comment: Why you are using Grid Layout? You want to add more rows or just one row with two items? If you want to use more then two rows (or indetermined) why you not  consider using GridView or GridLayout for a RecyclerView ?

Comment: i am thinking in add more rows. I dont known what you are talking about diogojme when you say Recycler viewer i am new in android

Comment: Consider if not using a ListView you will had to make a gigant layout file addint the rows manualy, and sometimes, you will never know the size of rows you will have, so thats why you have to use a ListView or GridView, both are concepts that you have to know before thinking in create a list or grid, please read about listviews and gridview: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/layout/listview.html
About the recycler view, is a new component in android that was created to replace listviews and gridviews, http://developer.android.com/training/material/lists-cards.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using fix `layout_width` and `layout_height` sizes at the `FrameLayout` and `ImageView` too. This way you wont reach the desired goal. You should use `wrap_content` value instead of fix sizes and play with the `layout_weight`. For example in a `LinearLayout` put two `FrameLayout` which contains the image and the text, after that add `layout_weight="1"` to the `FrameLayout` attributes.

Answer (score 0):

Don't use a frame layout.

Layout_weight is what you should use if you want to set your dimensions in relation to your view size(but don't nest weights as it quickly becomes very inefficient), or set the dimensions in your code based on the size of your view.

you hardcoded all of your view dimensions so they are always going to interact poorly with changes in screen size